# How to pass object to formdata which contains file object

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, multipartform-data, form-data

I want to pass following kind of  data to `webservice`

```
travelData = {
    "method": "add_edit_request",
    "params": {
        "request_by": requestOf,
        "purpose_of": travelPurpose,                            
        "filename":file_data
    }
};
```

where file_data is  `$("#fileInput").prop("files")[0];`

I want to pass files using `FormData`.

I have done following code to pass data using formData

```
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("method","add_edit_travel_request");

parameters={};
parameters["request_by"]=requestOf;
parameters["purpose_of_travel"]=travelPurpose;
parameters["filename"]=file_data;
formdata.append("params",JSON.stringify(parameters));
```

and i have ajax call of following type

```
return $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: 'POST',
            data: data,
            dataType:type,
            cache: false,
            crossDomain: true,
            contentType : false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);

                var args = arguments[2];
                callback.call(this, data, args.statusText, args);
            },
            fail: function(data) {

                xhrServerObj = xhr;
                errorcallback.call(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError);
            }
});
```

and calling it as

```
Utils.Ajax.uploadFile(Utils.WebAPI.WebAPIServer,formdata , this.RequestCallBack, 'json', this.RequestFailureCallBack);
```

Comment: why are you calling variable twice: var formdata = {};
                var formdata = new FormData(); ?

Comment: it is a typing mistake

Answer (score 0):

To pass object to `FormData` with contains a file object try using `Object.entries()`

```
// If this is the object you want to convert to FormData...
const item = {
    description: 'First item',
    price: 13,
    photo: File
};

const formData = new FormData();

Object.entries(item).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    formData.append(key, value);
});

// At this point, you can then pass formData to your handler method
```

Read more about `Object.entries()` over here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries